# xsl:variable does not return a node-set in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to get a node-set from a xsl variable for calculating. But my code only work with Opera, with other browsers, I keep getting the error.

Please help me fix to run with all browser. Thanks in advance.

Here are the xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="multipleSet">
 <xsl:for-each select="myNums/numSet">
  <xsl:element name="multiple"><xsl:value-of select="num1 * num2"/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>Num 1</th>
     <th>Num 2</th>
     <th>Multiple</th>
    </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="myNums/numSet">
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="num1"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="num2"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="num1 * num2"/></td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
    <tr>
     <th colspan="2" align="right">Total:</th>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="sum($multipleSet/multiple)"/> </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<myNums>
 <numSet>
  <num1>5</num1>
  <num2>5</num2>
 </numSet>
 <numSet>
  <num1>10</num1>
  <num2>5</num2>
 </numSet>
 <numSet>
  <num1>15</num1>
  <num2>20</num2>
 </numSet>
</myNums>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in other browsers?

Comment: IE: Reference to variable or parameter 'multipleSet' must evaluate to a node list. 
Firefox: Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath expression was expected to return a NodeSet.

Sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers usually don't support xslt 2.0. Xpath sum() expects a node-set. What you are passing it is a "result tree fragment". The result tree fragment data-type has been removed in XSLT 1.1. So what you are experiencing is:

- Opera doesn't tell you by an error message that it doesn't support xslt 2.0 ([Opera specification](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto25/#xml))
- Opera does not conform fully to 1.0 specification

You can try to specify `version="1.1"` and see if it helps. Otherwise, you may try if the browsers support [exsl:node-set()](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's my bad not to check xslt 2.0 support in the first place.

Using EXSLT will make everything go well, but not with IE, MS have their own msxsl extensions. I want to display the document on any browser with xslt 2.0, have to find another way though. 

Thanks for showing me the point. :)